# Is there a way to limit the max height of a Selectize field?

Tags: selectize.js

Is there a way to limit the max height of a [Selectize](https://selectize.dev/) field? The field itself, not the dropdown. The field does not restrict a maximum number of selections, so I can't use the `maxItems` option, nor can I use the `maxOptions` option because that applies to the dropdown.

[image]

```js
(function($select) {
  for (let i = 100; i < 202; ++i) {
    $select.append('<option value="' + i + '" selected>Test ' + i + '</option>');
    $select.append('<option value="' + (2 * i) + '">Test ' + (2 * i) + '</option>');
  }

  $select.selectize();
})($("#selectize"));
```

```css
#container {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="container" style="">
  <form>
    <select id="selectize" name="selectize" class="form-control" multiple></select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the `select` field in a container with CSS `max-height` and `overflow-y` set to "auto", and then setting the Selectize option `dropdownParent` to "body" seems to solve the problem.

Example: https://codepen.io/reformed05/pen/PoOYeye